# How can I move my logo 18px away from the left?

Tags: html, css, image, web, margin

My logo for my website is supposed to be in the top left of the page. Which it is, but right now its a little bit too close to left side. I want to move it 18px to the right. But I just can't get it to move. I tried to make a '.content img' for my logo but it did not work. Any ideas?

```css
      .content {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        z-index: 1000;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
      }
      .content h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 80px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: #fff;
        padding-top: 4.5%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .content p {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        color: #aaa;
      }

      .contect img {
        margin-left: 18px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src = "jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

  <script src = "script.js"></script>

  <link rel = "stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Passion+One|Source+Code+Pro" rel="stylesheet">

  <title> AL-SABA.net </title>

</head>

<body>

<header>

    <div class = "content"> 
                          <img src = "logo6.png" /> 

                          <h1> Title </h1>
                          <p>Design • Code • Programs </p>
    </div>

</header>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css'>

    <div class="background-wrap">
      <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted"> 
        <source src="coding.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Video not supported
      </video>          
    </div>

<div class="arrow bounce">
</div>

<footer>
</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you misspelled `.content` as `.contect`. Use `.content img` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a typo, it says ".contect img". Try this:

```
.content img {
    margin-left: 18px;
}
```